# Shared resources between User Controls in Winforms

Tags: winforms, user-controls, singleton

lets assume we have got these classes:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Controller controller;

    private uControl uc; //user control

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return Singleton.instance; }
    }

    public Controller GetController
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.controller == null)
            {
                this.controller = new Controller();
            }
            return this.controller;
        }
    }

    public uControl UC
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.uc == null)
            {
                this.uc = new uControl();
            }
            return this.uc;
        }
    }
}

public uControl : UserControl
{
    Controller controller = Singleton.Instance.GetController;

    // Do some work with controller class here ...
}

public Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(Singleton.Instance.UC);
    }
}

public Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(Singleton.Instance.UC);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add user control uControl via Singleton into two different forms and expect them to work correctly while accessing the same controller class?

When I try this only the form instantiated first will be able to display the uControl correctly. The other Form will get the uControll OK, but only empty space appears in the form where the user control should be ...

Comment: I don't think you can do that. It does not make sense either. UI is not Data. Implement the right patterns (MVC) or use a newer, relevant technology instead of winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you most definitely don't want to do that. the events of the control, it's position and a lot of other things of the user control are coming from it's parent control, and associate with it. what you can do is return a new user control with your own properties in it such as width and event handlers

Comment: I agree. After several experiments it proved unreasonable. If I'll find proper way to do this I will post the solution. Thank you for your help ...